# prove homogeneous markov chain

Tags: markov-chains, markov-process

$Y_0, Y_1,Y_2,\dots$ are independent and identically distributed random non-negative integer outcomes. Let X_0 = Y_0 $

Let $X_0 = Y_0$ and $X_n = X_{n-1} - Y_n$ if $X_{n-1}>0$, 
else $X_n = X_{n-1} + Y_n$.

Show $X_1,X_2,\dots$ is a homogeneous Markov chain. Any suggestions?

Edit: Here is my approach. I am not sure how sound it is but it's hopefully on the right path:

To prove it's time homogeneous, need to show :

$P(X_{n+1}=j\mid X_n=i) = P(X_1=j\mid X_0=i)$ (by definition)

$P(X_1=j\mid X_0=i)=P(X_1=X_0-Y_1=j\mid X_0=i)=P(i-Y_1=j\mid i)$

if $(i>0)$ $P(Y_1=j-i)$, else $P(Y_1=i-j)$ which are equals.

Similarly for $P(X_{n+1}=j\mid X_n=i)$ =>

if $(i>0)$ $P(Y_n=j-i)$ else $P(Y_n=i-j)$

Because $Y_1,Y_n$ are IID though, these probabilities are the same.

Comment: I've edited your post for readability, could you please check that I haven't accidentally changed the meaning anywhere. By the way, in equation (3) you have conditional probabilities with states $i$ and $-i$ on the right hand side. This makes no sense. The event that you condition on has to be $X_0=i$, or $X_n=i$, or something like that. Which random variable did you mean there?

Comment: The symbol $P(Y_n=i-j\mid i)$ makes no sense. What are you conditioning on?

Comment: i am just trying to transform them to P(Y_1) = P(Y_N) thus equal.

Answer (score 1):

Define the function $f(x,y)=x+\left({\bf 1}_{(-\infty,0]}(x)-{{\bf 1}_{(0,\infty)}(x)}\right)y.$ Then $X_n=f(X_{n-1},Y_n)$ for $n>0$, and if $({\cal F}_n)_{n\geq 0}$ is the filtration generated by $(X_n)_{n\geq 0}$, then 
$$\mathbb{P}(X_n\in B\mid {\cal F}_{n-1})= \mathbb{P}(f(X_{n-1},Y_n)\in B\mid {\cal F}_{n-1})=\mu(X_{n-1},B),$$
where we define the kernel $\mu(x,B)=\mathbb{P}(f(x,Y)\in B)$ for any random variable $Y$ distributed like every $Y_n$. This shows that $(X_n)_{n\geq 0}$ is Markov with transition kernel $\mu$.

Comment: this sounds fairly complicated and a bit above my head. Also I think the key point to prove is the homogeneous aspect. Unless you idea also covers that but it was not clear to me.

Comment: @pipodnmy The fact that my function $f$ doesn't depend on $n$ shows that the chain is homogeneous. If you could explain the methods that you usually use to solve such problems, and show your attempted solution, I could point to a more appropriate approach.

Comment: @Did Thanks for the edit. I should have emphasized that the $Y_n$s need to be identically distributed, as well.

Comment: i edited a different attempt. Is that any better?